# How do I change fill color when cutting a selection in MTPaint?

Tags: windows

When I use the rectangle selection tool in [MTPaint](http://mtpaint.sourceforge.net/), and I say have the color black selected as the primary color and white as the secondary color, if I cut the selection it makes the selection black instead of keeping it white like the canvas color is.

How do I make it so that when I cut a selection it keeps it white like in MS Paint?

Comment: Is [this GIF](https://i.gyazo.com/8a62be79341958d6dc55a72dc7aac9e4.gif) doing what you're describing?

Comment: Yes except the cutouts are not white as they should be, they are whatever my primary color is.